# webpack try to require a module that might be missing

Tags: webpack

I want to try to `require` a module in a webpack build and if that file is not found just do nothing, don't throw an error etc.

I tried doing it this way:

```
try {
  const local = require('./config-local.js');
  extend(config, local);
} catch (err) {
  // do nothing here
}
```

Basically what I want to do is to extend a config object with a local config if that file is found but if it isn't just don't extend it with anything.

Webpack throws an error that module is missing even though that require is wrapped in a try/catch clause.

How to tell webpack to ignore it?

Comment: This is in nodejs or client code?

Comment: Webpack treats every require as a resource and if its not there it will fail. Cant you just keep a file with empty object or something?

Comment: Problematic because I want to have this file gitignored :/

Comment: So every developer has to add it in his own workspace. How I do this in my project is, I have a grunt task which runs before webpack which takes care of creating config files (which are downloaded from some remote config management server).

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm thinking listening to an event might work, but I'm not sure which one and that seems a little excessive.

Comment: I solved it by creating a dummy config-local.js on post-install (from npm install) if one doesn’t exist already. Not a real solution to the problem but works in my case

Comment: This may have been fixed already, or at least caught in a smarter way. `webpack` is throwing errors for the hard-coded paths (require('some/nonexistent/path.js')), not dynamic paths (require(`some/${dynamic}/path`). This may not be right for some people, but I think it's just a warning and there may be an option to turn it off. I would post an answer, but I'm just speculating.

Comment: Is checking whether the file exists a problem for you? I mean, because it is async. If not you could try it.

Answer (score 3):

Webpack tries to bundle each one of your require into the output file. It does a static analysis finds a require and tries to read it. Your try&catch will work only in runtime.

All you need to do is to “mark” this require as special.

You can do it by using webpack’s special require: [__ webpack_require__](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#__webpack_require__-webpack-specific) which won't be parsed at build time, and will become a regular `require` in the bundle.

```js
try {
  const local = __webpack_require__('./config-local.js');
  extend(config, local);
} catch (err) {
  // do nothing here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @trysis comment, I ended up doing this in my project:

```js
const REQUIRE_TERMINATOR = '';
try {
  const local = require(`./config-local.js${REQUIRE_TERMINATOR}`);
  extend(config, local);
} catch (err) {
  // do nothing here
}
```

This will give WebPack enough information to include all files starting with `config-local.js` (which will be exactly the file you want), but also confuse it enough that it won't try to verify file's existence ahead of time, so your try/catch block will trigger during runtime.

Answer (score -1):

I think a slightly different approach might give you the result you want. You mention that the file in question is application config; I would handle this in `webpack.config.js` rather than in the application code. There your `require` will follow ordinary nodeJS rules rather than webpack's static analysis. You can try/catch the require statement and land on the resulting config that the app will use, then inject that config into the app using the `DefinePlugin`. IMO using `DefinePlugin` (with data from a static file or env variables) like this is a more common pattern for injecting config into a webpack-built application.

```
// load config data
const defaultConfig = require("default-config.json");
let localConfig = {};
try {
  localConfig = require("config-that-may-not-exist.json");
} catch (err) {}

const actualConfig = Object.assign(defaultConfig, localConfig);

// ...later, in plugins part of config:
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin(actualConfig)
]
```